# Add real path in url rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I try to rewritte my URL, and access to test page ( test.php ) , in the url the real path is add, so, I have a **404 error.**

> http://mywebsite.fr/home/web/dev/test/ <- /home/web/ is the real path
>   and it can't add to the URL.

In my configuration, I have writting this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName *
        ServerAlias *

        DocumentRoot /home/web
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>
```

In my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add extensions to your URLs like `.php` or `.html` then remove those shown rules from .htaccess and add this line:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.